# Get Broadcom Wifi Card [14e4:43ae] to work

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, 15.10

The Wifi isn't working, I'm not able to create a new (wifi) connection in the Network Settings.

As mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) I should ask a new question, if I have PCI ID that's not listed and well sadly I've got one : 14e4:43ae. I'm running the newest version of Ubuntu. `uname -r` returns `4.2.0-18-generic`.

`sudo lspci -vnn`

```
...
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0622]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRG 255
    Memory at d4800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at d4400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-08-ff-ff-00-30-0e
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] #15
...
```

`sudo lshw`

```
...
*pci:1
    description: PCI bridge
    product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    description: id: 1c.2
    bus info: pci@0000_00_1c-2
    version: e3
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33 MHz
    capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=pcieport
    resources: irq:18 memory:d4400000-d48fffff
   *-network UNCLAIMED
        description: Network controller
        product: Broadcom Corporation
        vendor: Broadcom Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
        version: 02
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
        configuration: latency=0
        resources: memory:d4800000-d4807ffff memory:d4400000-d47fffff
...
```

The output of `sudo lshw | grep wireless` is empty.

EDIT: I'm now really getting annoyed by this Broadcom Chip! Anyway, I ordered an Intel Wifi Chip and I'm going to replace my current with it.

Comment: Same problem here (although on Arch, but it's all roughly the same kernel). Lenovo Yoga 500 14" laptop.

Comment: The official Broadcom driver ("Linux® STA 64-bit driver"), of which `bcmwl-kernel-source` is just a repackaging, does not see this device. The PCI device ID is not in any database that I can find, either... did you have any success at least identifying the name of the chip?

Comment: No, sadly not...

Comment: Meanwhile, I think I've found it's a BCM43162. Which is indeed not listed as supported (or unsupported) anywhere that I could find. I tried ndiswrapper as well, but apparently the driver I threw at it was for too new a Windows version, because it complained about a lot of undefined symbols. I've given up for now as well, and I hope Linux support for this chip will appear some day.

Comment: Hmm well thats unfortunate.. If I had the time I would try writing the driver by myself but I think it's easier (and probably quicker) to buy a supported wifi chip...