# Wifi doesn't work after fresh install of 16.04

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo notebook with a Broadcom network device. My wifi isn't working. I tried to activate a private driver, but that didn't work.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Not a duplicate of that thread because his card isn't supported.

Comment: Not that it helps now but http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/ lists devices that are guaranteed to work. is your device listed there

Comment: Add information of `lshw -c network`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may need to install drivers for your wireless card.

First, can you please go into the terminal and type

`lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

and tell me what it returns to you?

Also run this: `iwconfig` after and post the results, too.

Reference: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

**EDIT:**

It appears that this wifi card is not yet supported according to other users and its not listed in the package install table in the previous link.

[Get Broadcom Wifi Card [14e4:43ae] to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703467/get-broadcom-wifi-card-14e443ae-to-work)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296434

Comment: Thanks for asking!!

Results:

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ae] (rev 02)

Comment: enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: Ok, in order to install the driver you need, you'll need some sort of Internet connection. Do you have an Ethernet cable you can use? I'll edit my answer to list the steps you must take.

Comment: Great! Yes, i have a ethernet conection. I will be here :)

Comment: My dearest apologies, I'm sorry to inform you that your wifi card is not yet supported.  There hasn't been a workaround found yet; most people advise buying another wireless card. I put links of what other people have tried to do to fix it, but there has been no resolve. Sorry I couldn't be of help!

Comment: Oh, thats bad... What can I do? I don't want back to  Windows :'(

If there's nothing to do, thank you very much anyway!!

Comment: You can purchase another wireless card thats supported by Ubuntu. You can find a list of them here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

These are the only Broadcom wireless cards that are currently supported on Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsBroadcom

You might have to pay to get it installed at a tech support location unless if you are comfortable with installing it yourself.

Comment: If you want a wireless card that will work on Ubuntu right after you install it (without needing to install packages), Intel ones work very well (See "out of the box"): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsIntel

Comment: AskUbuntu isn't a forum. Answer section is only for answers. Whatever diagnostic questions there are must be asked in comments below original question.